# How to instal JQ without homebrew?

Tags: macos, jq

I use Mac , how can I install JQ without home brew ? I installed 'jq-osx-amd64 'and executed this comments :

```
chmod +x ~/Downloads/*jq-osx-amd64* cp ~/Downloads/jq-osx-amd64 /usr/local/bin
```

After that when I try the open/execute jq-osx-amd64 the terminal pop up with :

> “jq-osx-amd64” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.

I opened the system preferences and allowed it but still doesn’t accept the permission and I couldn’t use the jq. Any help will be appreciated . Thank you

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want to insteall it via Homebrew ?

Comment: Hi , I tried the homebrew and I came across early EOF error, currently I could not use it

Comment: If you are behind corporate firewalls and corporate cyber security rules that don't let you install homebrew...  I'm in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer , you need to run this command :

```
xattr -dr com.apple.quarantine /usr/local/bin/jq
```

But might want to change file name with this command :

```
mv /usr/local/bin/jq-oxs-amd64 /usr/local/bin/jq
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to let your Mac know that you trust the developer of `jq-osx-amd64`

---

After the *cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified*, follow these steps:

1. Open settings
2. Go to `Security & Privacy`
3. Go to the `General` Tab
4. You'll see something like

   > `jq-osx-amd64` was blocked from use bevause it is not from an identified developer

   To Allow this, press the `Allow Anyway` button

   [image]
5. Invoke `jq-osx-amd64` once again from your terminal
6. Accept the `unknown developer` popup by pressing `Open`
   [Picture showing popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeYR7.png)
7. Invoke `jq-osx-amd64` once again

Comment: actually I tried this way but it could not work , thank you

Answer (score 0):

Since the other fine answers here involve bypassing Apple's security for unknown executables, it's a good idea to **compare the SHA checksum** of the jq binary that you download to the published checksum in Github.

`shasum -a 256 <downloaded jq>` should generate a value that you can find in the most recent sha256 page (currently
https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/master/sig/v1.7.1/sha256sum.txt )

For example,

```
% shasum -a 256 jq-macos-arm64
0bbe619e663e0de2c550be2fe0d240d076799d6f8a652b70fa04aea8a8362e8a  jq-macos-arm64
```

matches https://github.com/jqlang/jq/blob/913b26469f47351a9f75a1bc4145f45421115e37/sig/v1.7.1/sha256sum.txt#L22C1-L22C81

Answer (score -1):

You could use [macports](/questions/tagged/macports) or 0install or [asdf-vm](/questions/tagged/asdf-vm) or ...
See https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation